# Загрузка файлов на сервер, + надо загружать mp3 файлы с лимитом времени трека 2 минуты

Tags: ajax, php, javascript, сервер

С загрузкой файлов на сервер, еще не сталкивался, ajax знаю вполне хорошо, объясните как это сделать, хотя б просто загрузить файлы на сервер ajax-ом. Спасиб.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые специально задают размусоленные по 1000 раз вопросы?

- [Принципы так называемой "AJAX загрузки файлов на сервер"](http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=46&topic=17)
- [AJAX загрузка файлов на сервер + jQuery, IFRAME, PHP](http://aron8.slineup.com/?p=275)
- [Ajax загрузка нескольких файлов на сервер](http://php-zametki.ru/javascript-laboratoriya/77-ajax-zagruzka-neskolkix-fajlov-na-server.html)
- [AJAX загрузка файлов на сервер + jQuery, IFRAME, PHP](http://sitear.ru/material/ajax-zagruzka-failov-jquery-iframe-php)

P.S. Думаю проверять mp3 файл на время придётся отдельно.

---

По поводу времени посмотри [тут](http://ajaxian.com/archives/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript) и [обязательно тут](http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=64)

Comment: извиняйте, когда начал искать ответ на этот вопрос, искал в гугле, смотрю, читаю... и не будет лишним сюда написать, может кто советом поделиться! спасибо